# Python signxml XML signature package. How to add xml placehoder for Signature tag?

Tags: python, xml, xml-signature

I am new to Python. I have installed signxml package and I am doing xml signature process.

Link to python package : https://pypi.org/project/signxml/

My xml file is getting generated. However XML signature code is little different. I was able to match most of the part but I donot have idea how to match following one.

Can any one please help me for that.

**Different part is following tag**

```
<Signature>
```

**Above part should be like this one**

```
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
```

[image]

When i searched into signxml core file i found following note.

```
To specify the location of an enveloped signature within **data**, insert a
``<ds:Signature Id="placeholder"></ds:Signature>`` element in **data** (where
"ds" is the "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" namespace). This element will
be replaced by the generated signature, and excised when generating the digest.
```

How to make change to get this changed.
Following is my python code

```
from lxml import etree
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from signxml import XMLSigner, XMLVerifier
import signxml

el = ET.parse('example.xml')
root = el.getroot()

#cert = open("key/public.pem").read()
key = open("key/private.pem").read()

signed_root = XMLSigner(method=signxml.methods.enveloped,signature_algorithm='rsa-sha512',digest_algorithm="sha512").sign(root, key=key)

tree = ET.ElementTree(signed_root)


#dv = tree.findall(".//DigestValue");
#print(dv);

tree.write("new_signed_file.xml")
```

What above code doing is. It takes one xml file and do digital signature process and generates new file.

Can anyone please guide me where and what change should i do for this requirements ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you are using python **signxml**

Go to python setup and open this file **Python\Lib\site-packages\signxml\ __init__.py**

Open **__init__.py** file and do following changes.

Find following code

```
def _unpack(self, data, reference_uris):
        sig_root = Element(ds_tag("Signature"), nsmap=self.namespaces)
```

Change with following code.

```
def _unpack(self, data, reference_uris):
        #sig_root = Element(ds_tag("Signature"), nsmap=self.namespaces)
        sig_root = Element(ds_tag("Signature"), xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#")
```

After doing this change **re-compile your python signxml package**.

Re-generate new xml signature file.