# Problem generating and verifying signature with signxml in python (namespaces and signature)

Tags: python, xml, elementtree, xml-signature

sorry for my english firstly. I'm taking my first steps with signxml in Python, and from the articles I've seen it looks quite easy to use, but I haven't been able to correctly sign the document as I need it.

I was looking at the documentation and some articles on the web, and among the problems I was having when signing a document with signxml, I found an article at https://technotes.shemyak.com/posts/xml-signatures-with-python-elementtree/. So I tried to use my data with this structure.

```
ET.register_namespace("ds", "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#")

xml_con_semilla = ET.fromstring("<getToken><item><Semilla>000009574333</Semilla></item><ds:Signature xmlns:ds=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#\" Id=\"placeholder\"></ds:Signature></getToken>")
```

Here they explain some of the difficulties at the time of signing and verification. Using the method on this website I got the correct signature and verification even of the serialized data at the end of the steps, but when I send the xml to the service I need, it gives me problems. I suppose it must be because it does not have the structure that is requested.

The structure that the service is waiting for is the following

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<getToken>
    <item>
        <Semilla>000009574333</Semilla>
    </item>
    <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <SignedInfo>
            <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
            <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
            <Reference URI="">
                <Transforms>
                    <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
                </Transforms>
                <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                <DigestValue>XX...</DigestValue>
            </Reference>
        </SignedInfo>
        <SignatureValue>XX...</SignatureValue>
        <KeyInfo>
            <KeyValue>
                <RSAKeyValue>
                    <Modulus>XX...</Modulus>
                    <Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
                </RSAKeyValue>
            </KeyValue>
            <X509Data>
                <X509Certificate>XX...</X509Certificate>
            </X509Data>
        </KeyInfo>
    </Signature>
</getToken>
```

So I'm doing a clean try, from an XML generated with etree, since I think the above solution doesn't satisfy what I need.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import signxml

semilla = '000009574333'
xml_semilla = ET.Element('getToken')
item = ET.SubElement(xml_semilla, 'item')
ET.SubElement(item, 'Semilla').text = semilla

>>> <getToken><item><Semilla>000009574333</Semilla></item></getToken>

semilla_xml_firmada = FirmarXMLSemilla(xml_semilla)
```

```
def FirmarXMLSemilla(xml_semilla):
 
    pem_cert, pem_key = [open(f, "rb").read() for f in ("cert.pem", "key.pem")]

    signer = XMLSigner(method=signxml.methods.enveloped,
                       signature_algorithm='rsa-sha1',
                       c14n_algorithm='http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315',
                       digest_algorithm="sha1")

    signed_root = signer.sign(xml_semilla, key=pem_key, cert=pem_cert, always_add_key_value=True)

    try:
        verified_data = XMLVerifier().verify(signed_root, x509_cert=pem_cert)
        print('Documento Firmado Correctamente')
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error('Error de Verificación en la Firma o Respuesta SAML: {}'.format(e))
```

Up to this point, without serializing, the signature is correct

```
VerifyResult(signed_data=b'<getToken><item><Semilla>000009574333</Semilla></item></getToken>', signed_xml=<Element getToken at 0x24cd69e65c0>, signature_xml=<Element {http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#}Signature at 0x24cd69e6640>)
```

```
    data_serialized = ET.tostring(signed_root)
```

```
data_serialized =
<getToken xmlns:ns0="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <item>
        <Semilla>000009574333</Semilla>
    </item>
    <ns0:Signature>
        <ns0:SignedInfo>
            <ns0:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
            <ns0:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
            <ns0:Reference URI="">
                <ns0:Transforms>
                    <ns0:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                </ns0:Transforms>
                <ns0:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                <ns0:DigestValue>XX...</ns0:DigestValue>
            </ns0:Reference>
        </ns0:SignedInfo>
        <ns0:SignatureValue>XX...</ns0:SignatureValue>
        <ns0:KeyInfo>
            <ns0:KeyValue>
                <ns0:RSAKeyValue>
                    <ns0:Modulus>XX...</ns0:Modulus>
                    <ns0:Exponent>AQAB</ns0:Exponent>
                </ns0:RSAKeyValue>
            </ns0:KeyValue>
            <ns0:X509Data>
                <ns0:X509Certificate>XX...</ns0:X509Certificate>
            </ns0:X509Data>
        </ns0:KeyInfo>
    </ns0:Signature>
</getToken>
```

```
    # Sending the data...
    data_parsed = ET.fromstring(data_serialized)

    try:
        verified_data = XMLVerifier().verify(data_parsed, x509_cert=pem_cert)
        print('Documento Firmado Correctamente')
        logging.debug(verified_data)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error('Error de Verificación en la Firma o Respuesta SAML: {}'.format(e))
```

```
ERROR:root:Error de Verificación en la Firma o Respuesta SAML: Signature verification failed: bad signature
```

As you will notice, when converting to a string, namespaces are added to the data, which breaks the signature. In addition, the "ns0:" prefixes are added.

I need xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" to be added to Signature, not getToken

I also tried [Python signxml XML signature package. How to add xml placehoder for Signature tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61138256/python-signxml-xml-signature-package-how-to-add-xml-placehoder-for-signature-ta) but it also gives me problems.

I am using signxml version 3.0.1, so that it will allow me to use SHA-1.

Thanks!

Comment: The `xmlns` declaration *must* be added to the root element, so the output you show is correct. The namespace is only *applied* to the `<Signature>` element (that's why you see `<getToken>`, with no namespace, and `<ns0:Signature>`, which is using the `http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#` namespace.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It seems like the issue is the way you are saving your XML. If you use etree it should do the trick.

```
        with open('key.pem', 'rb') as key_file:
            private_key_data = key_file.read()

        private_key = serialization.load_pem_private_key(
            private_key_data,
            password=None,  # Add your passphrase if the key is encrypted
            backend=default_backend()
        )
        with open('cer.rec.pem', 'rb') as cert_file:
            certificate = cert_file.read()
        tree = ET.parse('path_to_xml.xml')
        root = tree.getroot()

        signer = XMLSigner(
            method=methods.enveloped,
            c14n_algorithm='http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315#WithComments'
        )
        # signer.sign_alg = SignatureMethod('http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1')
        signer.namespaces = {None: namespaces.ds}

        # Pass the private key object and certificate bytes to the signer
        signed_xml = signer.sign(
            root,
            key=private_key,
            # cert=certificate,
            always_add_key_value=True,
        )
        # XMLVerifier().verify(signed_xml)
        
        final_signed_xml = etree.ElementTree(signed_xml)
        final_signed_xml.write('signed_xml.xml', encoding='UTF-8', xml_declaration=False)
```

also, with the `signer.namespaces = {None: namespaces.ds}` you should be able to eliminate namespaces.